# is - select * from empty table possible?

Tags: javascript, sql

On my website I am trying to select 2 tables - tableB of which might be empty, so its not returning any results at all when tableB is empty. I hope I am explaining this properly. Any suggestions?

```
    curatio.webdb.getAllTodoItems = function(renderFunc) {
        var db = curatio.webdb.db;
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tableA, tableB", [], renderFunc,
                curatio.webdb.onError);
        });
    }
```

basically TableA has e.g. Name and Surname columns and TableB has e.g. Address details. But sometimes there is no address, and then I cannot get anything to display.

I need to basically ignore tableB if it's empty.

Comment: What is the purpose of that query? I.e. what are you trying to retrieve from the database?

Comment: I think you may want UNION but it's not clear what you want vs what's happening

Comment: Bart, basically TableA has e.g. Name and Surname columns and TableB has e.g. Address details. But sometimes there is no address, and then I cannot get anything to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your query doesn't hint at this, I still think you are probably looking for a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join), because I'm assuming you want to link data from two tables by a common value in a column from table B (known as the foreign key).

This query selects values of the first table, even when there's no matching data in the join table:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tableA` `a`
LEFT JOIN `tableB` `b`
  ON `b`.`someReferenceColumnToTableA` = `a`.`theReferredColumn`
```

Again, this assumes you meant to join two tables by some common value, for instance:

```
person (table A):
- id
- name

phonenumber (table B):
- id
- person_id // this is the foreign key to table A that "links" the data
- phonenumber
```

If you were to use a regular `JOIN` (also known as `INNER JOIN`) then only rows are returned for when both tables have matching data.

What your original query did, however, was (implicitly) [`CROSS JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) all data from both tables. Given your question edit, I hardly think this is what you were actually after.

Comment: fireeyedboy, yes your answer worked best here. Thanks for spotting that

Answer (score 1):

If tableA and tableB have the same schema, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT * FROM tableB
```

However, if they don't have the same schema, you will have to do something smarter to get the union to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are performing there is called a Cross-Product of those two tables.  A cross-product is essentially every row of tableA with every row of tableB.  Since tableB has no rows, the cross-product has no rows.  If you want all rows of both tables, use 2 queries.  I would recommend reading a basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: Hi jgitter, even though I thought you were a complete ass with that last sentence, your answer was actually the right one. By editing it to two queries it is now working. Thanks

Comment: No offense was intended.  We all had to start somewhere.  I made the same mistake many years ago.

Comment: That `SELECT * FROM my_table` is everything that's worth learning about SQL is a fairly extended idea. Some people even think that SQL is not a language of its own but part of PHP. Sorry but joins are the foundation of relational databases—if you aren't willing to learn it's up to you but your comment against jgitter was out of place.

Answer (score 0):

```
curatio.webdb.getAllTodoItems = function(renderFunc) {
    var db = curatio.webdb.db;
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tableA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tableB", [], renderFunc,
            curatio.webdb.onError);
    });
}
```

It will best to explicitly use the column names in both select rather then using the `*`.

Comment: When I try UNION, I get the following error: (1 SELECTs to the left and right of UNION do not have the same number of result columns)

Comment: Thats why I said use the column names in both select statements, [`Read here`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) more about union operator in sql.